# get rgb data from image files using python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb

I can do very simple things.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poVTx.png)

when i run this code, I can get just one pixel data.
I want to get all of the rgb values from image file.
and save it as txt file

How can I do?

thank you

Comment: in the picture, "print(a)" was mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pix = list(im.getdata())
```

Will get a list of all the RGB pixels for your image.